# Passing Parameters in HLSL with Tessellation

Tags: parameters, directx, shader, hlsl, tessellation

My question is hopefully very simple but I can't seem to get the flow of data correct. The issue is how to pass texture coordinates and normal data from a vertex shader through the tessellation stages (Hull and Domain shader) and into the pixel shader for rendering.

The problem I am encountering is that before the use of tesselation the data could simply be passed from vertex to pixel shader. There is now multiple steps between these two shaders a patch constant function the hull shader and then the domain shader.

If anyone can give me some insight into how to pass data through each of these sections , and if possible maybe some quick pseudo code to demonstrate it, I'd be very thankful. If you need more information, or my current code (even though it doesn't work), just let me know.

Extra information: The program is written in C++ using DirectX 11 api using HLSL.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think your question is a little broad for SO; make an attempt, show what you've tried, and others will be able to better assist.

Comment: Hi, sorry i didnt want to post any of the code i have due to it being across multiple files and is pretty large in size. was just hoping for some insight into the data flow of shaders when using tesselation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I used to create the tessellation, I hide the some code to show only the necessary for you. 
ps: tess_factor is a parameter of constant buffer.

```
HS_OUTPUT_DATA hs_patch(InputPatch<VERTEX_PASS, 3> ip, uint pid : SV_PrimitiveID)
{
HS_OUTPUT_DATA ret;
float tess = tess_factor;
ret.edges[0] = ret.edges[1] = ret.edges[2] = tess;
ret.inside = tess; // same value that edges
return ret;
}

[domain("tri")]
[partitioning("integer")] // integer, fractional_even, fractional_odd
[outputtopology("triangle_cw")]
[outputcontrolpoints(3)]
[patchconstantfunc("hs_patch")]
HS_OUTPUT hs(InputPatch<VERTEX_PASS, 3> ip, uint index : SV_OutputControlPointID)
{
HS_OUTPUT ret;
ret.pos = ip[index].pos;
return ret;
}

[domain("tri")]
VERTEX_PASS ds(HS_OUTPUT_DATA input, float3 dl : SV_DomainLocation, const     
OutputPatch<HS_OUTPUT, 3> bp)
{
    VERTEX_PASS ret;
    ret.pos = bp[0].pos * dl.x + bp[1].pos * dl.y + bp[2].pos * dl.z;
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the constant buffer of Vertex, Hull, Domain and Pixel Shader are separated. in the code behind of application set your parameters in the constant buffers that you use:

```
ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetConstantBuffers
ID3D11DeviceContext::HSGetConstantBuffers
```

The first function set constant buffers to Pixel Shader use. The second set for the Hull Shader. But in your case you must pass the parameters forward using your structs. This is my code for passing only the color:

```
struct VERTEX_PASS
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

struct HS_OUTPUT_DATA
{
    float4 pos : WORLDPOS;
    float4 color : COLOR;
    float edges[3] : SV_TessFactor; // not using in this example
    float inside : SV_InsideTessFactor; // not using in this example
};

HS_OUTPUT_DATA hs_patch(InputPatch<VERTEX_PASS, 3> ip, uint pid : SV_PrimitiveID)
{
    HS_OUTPUT_DATA ret;
    ret.color = ip[pid].color; // pass the color to forward
    return ret;
}
```

The texture coordinate is same idea, but the color are constant in all vertices, in case of texture coordinates, in domain shader stage, you must calculate the new UV coordinate like you calculate the final vertex position.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a simple example since you didn't explain your situation like error message or so.

Here's one: http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut38.html

The author explained almost every line of the code briefly, you can see the part of tessellation stages to understand how to define the data structure between each stage of the rendering pipeline.

And also I suggest you compile your shader code with debug information enabled.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/ff476261(v=vs.85).aspx

With that you can know what's wrong with your shader program, maybe you could solve it by yourself immediately.

I wanted to just comment below but somehow the comment button disappeared.